# How to get to Web API's sessionStorage object in React

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, redux

I don't get it, I see all these people talking about localStorage or sessionStorage yet in my React project I have undefined.  How are they getting that object from a real Web API?

Examples:

[persistent-state-reactjs](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/03/05/persistent-state-reactjs)

[redux-sessionstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-sessionstorage)

[react-redux-jwt-auth-example](https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example/blob/master/src/index.js)

each one of these shows calling localStorage or sessionStorage but how?  I don't see them using any libs to get to that.  The only thing I can figure is they're using something like phantom or casper??  I only see phantom in the package.json of that third url.  Even so, I don't see how he's pluging up Phantom and if not how does he have an instance of localStorage?
[image]

Comment: Is your app server rendered? If so then you won't get localStorage and sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) are built-in objects from the Web API, so you don't need any libraries to use them **IF** you are using them in the **front end**. My guess is that, `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` is not available because your react app is server rendered. You can test them by running the code below somewhere in your app. If they don't exists and you still want your app to be server rendered, you may use a library such as this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-storage.

```js
try {
  // localstorage or sessionstorage init
  // ...
} catch (e) {
  // they are not defined, use a library
  console.log(e); // look at error
  
  // if localStorage is not defined, use a library
  window.localStorage = require('web-storage')().localStorage;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: when you say server rendered, this isn't an isomorphic app.  I'm simply using react-redux.

Comment: I think I might've missed something. What does the code code `let token = localStorage.getItem('token')` resolves to? Is it null or undefined? What happens when you `console.log(localStorage)`?